# FileOutputStream сгенерировать имя файла автоматический

Tags: java, файлы

Можно ли сгенерировать имя файла автоматический а не указывать его вручную

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("z:/test.docx"));
```

Comment: А вы пробовали в new File() передавать строковую переменную?

Comment: нет не побывал, а как?!

Comment: Начните с чтения книжек, если вы не понимаете таких вещей. С такими знаниями мне придется писать весь код за вас, а я этого не хочу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать GUID

- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID
- http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Для использования - нужно импортировать java.util.UUID. Использовать можно как то так:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("z:/" + uuid.toString() +".docx"));
```